# How to query height of a given lat long coordinate from server side?

Tags: terrain

I need to some calculation with terrain surface, I use **cesium** but it works slow.
Cesium has a method [sampleTerrainMostDetailed](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/sampleTerrainMostDetailed.html), it gives me height of given coordinates but it calculates height on client.

`sampleTerrainMostDetailed` works like this:

1. create tiles array which is which points inside which tile
2. request tiles array from terrain
3. and interpolate coordinate height from terrain data

This process happen in client and it's slow.

I want to do this in server side, but I don't know **is there any service gives me height of given coordinate** like `sampleTerrainMostDetailed` method ?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Global? Local? 100m resolution? 1 meter resolution? 1 cm resolution?

Comment: I mean I try to learn is there any service for that or, should I write program for that, I explain what I try to do, may be there is a keyword for that which is I dont know or there are some tools do that already.